# Setting system properties with "sbt run"

Tags: sbt

I'm using a pretty recent version of SBT (seems to be hard to figure out what the version is). I want to pass system properties to my application with `sbt run` as follows:

```
sbt -Dmyprop=x run
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

SBT's runner doesn't normally create new processes, so you also have to tell it to do this if you want to set the arguments that are passed. You can add something like this to your build settings:

```
fork := true

javaOptions := Seq("-Dmx=1024M")
```

There's more detail on forking processes in [the SBT documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Forking.html).

Comment: How might you do this at the command line w/ the run command?

Comment: Chad has asked this as a separate question over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389392/

Answer (score 10):

I found the best way to be adding this to `build.sbt`:

```
// important to use ~= so that any other initializations aren't dropped
// the _ discards the meaningless () value previously assigned to 'initialize'
initialize ~= { _ =>
  System.setProperty( "config.file", "debug.conf" )
}
```

Related: When doing this to change the Typesafe Configuration that gets loaded (my use case), one needs to also manually include the default config. For this, the Typesafe Configuration's suggested `include "application"` wasn't enough but `include classpath("application.conf")` worked. Thought to mention since some others may well be wanting to override system properties for precisely the same reason.

Source: [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/o1iGaMi4UeU) on the sbt mailing list

Comment: Turns out that 'some other' was myself, only 8 days later. Had managed to somehow get the 'classpath()' part lost. Reason #1 for StackOverflow entries is to serve as reminder for ourselves...

Comment: Note: For some reason this does no longer work if one wants to separately define it for 'in Test' elsewhere in build.sbt. All in all use of 'initialize' seems to be semi-documented at best, so I'm going for the 'fork := true' approach that Luke Taylor suggests.

Comment: that's a shame as I preferred your approach. Do you still fork a separate JVM after setting `javaOptions`?

Comment: I've stuck using the 'fork := true' approach

Comment: I tried that too today and it's working for me as well :). Thanks your getting back to me.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the pointer, this actually helped me solve a somewhat related problem with Scala Tests.

It turned out that `sbt` *does* fork the tests when there are sub-projects (see my  [code](http://github.com/massenz/sentinel)) and some of the tests fail to pick up the system property.

So in `sbt -Dsomething="some value" test`, some of the tests would fail when failing to find `something` in the system properties (that happened to be my DB URI, so it kinda mattered!)

This was driving me nuts, so I thought I'd post it here for future reference for others (as @akauppi correctly noted, chances are high that "others" may well be me in a few weeks!).

The fix was to add the following to `build.st`:

`fork in Test := false`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass system properties at the end of the sbt command:

```sh
sbt run -Dmyprop=x
```

If you have to pass program parameters into a stage, just pass system properties after the quotes again:

```sh
sbt "runMain com.example.MyClass -p param-value" -Dmyprop=x
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is to use the JAVA_OPTS environment variable:

```
#update the java options (maybe to keep previous options)
export JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dmyprop=x"
#now run without any extra option
sbt run
```