# How to set system properties for runMain on command line?

Tags: sbt

How can I set a system property for `runMain` upon executing it from command line on Windows?

I'd like to be able to run the following command:

```
sbt -Dconfig.resource=../application.conf "runMain akka.Main com.my.main.Actor"
```

Regardless of whether `fork` is true, whether I put it in `SBT_OPTS`, or how I pass it in I cannot accomplish this. I am familiar with both [Setting value of setting on command line when no default value defined in build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939554/how-can-i-set-a-setting-using-the-command-line-without-it-having-a-default-value) and [Setting system properties with "sbt run"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155870/scala-simple-build-tool-giving-your-program-system-properties-with-sbt-run) but neither answer my question.

Other questions seem to indicate you can't even easily view the Java invocation arguments easily in SBT. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: BTW, this works at least with sbt 1.x `sbt run -J-Dconfig.resource="../application.conf"`

Comment: This doesn't work, at least not in sbt 1.1.1. Adding `enVars in run := Map("config.resources" -> "blabla")` works though

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This works:

```
sbt '; set javaOptions += "-Dconfig.resource=../application.conf" ; runMain akka.Main com.my.main.Actor'
```

If this isn't a "friendly" enough syntax, wrap it in a little shell script.

(Note this assumes you have `fork` set to true for running. If you don't, see akauppi's comment.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm afraid that is about the best I can do.

Comment: No, that's not friendly enough. Is there a better way now?

Comment: I think this needs 'fork' to be enabled. Got it to work without fork (which was my need) by: sbt '; eval System.setProperty("config.file","fn.conf") ; test'

Comment: @akauppi this works great for calling something in main - but i can't get it working with any of my tests or integration tests

Comment: Replace with `javaOptions ++= Seq(...)` for brevity when overriding multiple options.

Comment: if you want to combine forking VMs with `set javaOpts`, use this in addition: ```javaOptions in ThisBuild ++= sys.props.get("config.resource")
  .map(value => s"-Dconfig.resource=$value").toSeq```

Comment: If you use `subproject/runMain` then it's `subproject/javaOptions`. Easy to forget.

Answer (score 18):

You could use `envVars` setting. I'm unsure how idiomatic it is in SBT, though.

```
> help envVars
Environment variables used when forking a new JVM
```

The following (very minimalistic) `build.sbt` worked fine.

```
fork := true

envVars := Map("msg" -> "hello")
```

Once you get it running, setting `envVars` to any value with `set` does the trick.

```
> help set
set [every] <setting-expression>

        Applies the given setting to the current project:
          1) Constructs the expression provided as an argument by compiling and loading it.
          2) Appends the new setting to the current project's settings.
          3) Re-evaluates the build's settings.

        This command does not rebuild the build definitions, plugins, or configurations.
        It does not automatically persist the setting(s) either.
        To persist the setting(s), run 'session save' or 'session save-all'.

        If 'every' is specified, the setting is evaluated in the current context
        and the resulting value is used in every scope.  This overrides the value
        bound to the key everywhere.
```

I've got a simple app to run.

```
$ sbt run
[info] Set current project to fork-testing (in build file:/C:/dev/sandbox/fork-testing/)
[info] Running Hello
[info] hello
```

With the `envVars` setting changed on the command line the output would change as follows:

```
$ sbt 'set envVars := Map("msg" -> "Hello, Chad")' run
[info] Set current project to fork-testing (in build file:/C:/dev/sandbox/fork-testing/)
[info] Defining *:envVars
[info] The new value will be used by *:runner, compile:run::runner and 1 others.
[info]  Run `last` for details.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to fork-testing (in build file:/C:/dev/sandbox/fork-testing/)
[info] Running Hello
[info] Hello, Chad
```

`runMain` is no different from `run` in this case.

```
$ sbt 'set envVars := Map("msg" -> "Hello, Chad")' 'runMain Hello'
[info] Set current project to fork-testing (in build file:/C:/dev/sandbox/fork-testing/)
[info] Defining *:envVars
[info] The new value will be used by *:runner, compile:run::runner and 1 others.
[info]  Run `last` for details.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to fork-testing (in build file:/C:/dev/sandbox/fork-testing/)
[info] Running Hello
[info] Hello, Chad
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was hoping for Java system properties, but I suppose I could set javaOptions via the "set". I was hoping for a more friendly way for my administrator to provide the path to his configuration, but it appears I just have to create a custom task or something.

Comment: BTW, Why do you want to run an app using SBT instead of leveraging [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager) at the very least?! All configuration would then be in a code repo and you'd also could automate deployments.

Comment: I want my administrator to provide this system property at his own leisure.

Comment: The following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37213752/pass-system-property-to-sbt-console answers my question.

Answer (score 6):

If you're trying to set SBT properties, like plugin settings, then the above won't work (AFAICT) as of `0.13+` in my experience. The following however did work, when trying to pass in Liquibase settings, like password, from our CI frameworks.

#### In your build.sbt

Ugly, but supplies defaults, and optionally grabs from *System.properties*. This way you've got your default and override cases covered.

```
def sysPropOrDefault(propName:String,default:String):String = Option(System.getProperty(propName)).getOrElse(default)

liquibaseUsername := sysPropOrDefault("liquibase.username","change_me")
liquibasePassword := sysPropOrDefault("liquibase.password","chuck(\)orris")
```

#### From the commandline

Now just override via `-Dprop=value` like you would with Maven or other JVM programs. Note props appear before SBT task.

`sbt -Dliquibase.password="shh" -Dliquibase.username="bob"  liquibase:liquibase-update`