# How to set System property for a scalatest from sbt command line

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

A ScalaTest suite is using

```
 System.getProperty("my.command-line.property")
```

What is the sbt command line to achieve this setting?

I have tried

```
SBT_OPTS="-Dmy.command-line.property=foo" sbt "test-only <path to test suite"
```

Also:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-J-Dmy.command-line.property=foo" sbt "test-only <path to test suite"
```

Finally:

```
sbt/sbt  '; set javaOptions in Test  +="-Dtest.num.points=500000"; \
project mllib; test-only org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.LBFGSSuite'
```

When using any of those attempts the System.getProperty comes up blank.

An approach that *does* work is running the ScalaTest from within Intellij and setting the JVM parameters to **-Dmy.command-line.property=foo** within the Run Configuration.

Comment: do you fork your tests? (do you have this line:`fork in Test := true` in your build files?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third way *almost* works (if `fork in Test := true` is set). But you have to change into the project first:

```
sbt/sbt  '; project mllib; set javaOptions in Test  +="-Dtest.num.points=500000"; \
test-only org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.LBFGSSuite'
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply that to every project?  I am trying to set a flag that limits logging during the CI build, but I wan't it set in every project.  And since it is only for CI, I need a command line option

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
val myFoo = sys.props("foo.property")
```

and:

```
SBT_OPTS="-Dfoo.property=foo" sbt "testOnly *your_test_package*"
```

Comment: Inside a scalatest suite?

Comment: The first line inside your test code, the second line command line (how to set your property and limit the test execution only to your desired package)

Answer (score 0):

With some suites you can override the `beforeAll()` hook and make the initialization there.  This doesn't guarantee that this initialization will be run before any Spark initialization at all, but it does make it early enough for many situations.

```
override def beforeAll() {
  super.beforeAll()
  System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", "C:\\dev\\Temp")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your project settings:

```
javaOptions in Test += "-Dmy.command-line.property=foo"
```

If you have lots of settings, you could place them in a config file and pass it like this:

```
javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/test.conf"
```

**EDIT:** To pass it from the command-line:
I guess you are after this answer: [How to set system properties for runMain on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389392/how-to-set-system-properties-for-runmain-on-command-line)

**EDIT 2**:
Did you try this ?
sbt '; set javaOptions += "-Dconfig.resource=../application.conf" ; test'

Comment: Your answers are not addressing the particulars of this question:  runMain is not applicable to scalatest

Comment: @javadba I did not give you the direct answer. You could have guessed the answer, :) If not see my `EDIT 2`

Comment: I partially agree: was molding my command line that way to see if scalatest can work with it.  Update: that approach does not apparently work with scalatest.

Comment: Edit 2 would work on unix but not on windows, as need double quote wrapper, any ideas on how could make this work on windows?