# Run sbt with differents jvm arguments

Tags: jvm, sbt, jvm-arguments

In my build.sbt :

```
name := "test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

fork in run := true

outputStrategy := Some(StdoutOutput)

javaOptions in run += "-XX:MaxPermSize=1024M"

javaOptions in run += "-XX:PermSize=1024M"

javaOptions in run += "-Xmx50G"

javaOptions in run += "-Xms50G"
```

My java options are static, I would like to set Xms and Xmx dynamically when I launch my application in the command line. Something like :

```
#sbt "run-main Main" arg_xmx arg_xms
```

Hypotetic build.sbt :

```
javaOptions in run += "-Xmx<arg_xmx>G"

javaOptions in run += "-Xms<arg_xms>G"
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly the method that I was looking for but the result is the same. I found thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389392/how-to-set-system-properties-for-runmain-on-command-line).

```
#sbt '; set javaOptions += "-Xms4G" ; set javaOptions += "-Xmx4G" ; run-main job.Main'
```