# Pass System Property to `sbt console`?

Tags: scala, sbt, system-properties

Borrowing from this helpful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389392/how-to-set-system-properties-for-runmain-on-command-line), I tried to pass `-Dfoo=bar` to `sbt console`.

Given an SBT project having only a `build.sbt`:

```
$cat build.sbt
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

fork := true
```

I attempted:

```
$sbt '; set javaOptions += "-Dfoo=bar" ; console'

scala> sys.props.get("foo")
res0: Option[String] = None
```

but, I had expected `Some("bar")` rather than `None` given the `set ...` argument.

However, using `sbt ... run` worked as expected:

```
$cat src/main/scala/net/Main.scala 
package net

object Main {
       def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = 
           println("sys.props.get('foo'): " + sys.props.get("foo"))
}

$sbt '; set javaOptions += "-Dfoo=bar" ; run'
[info] Running net.Main 
[info] sys.props.get('foo'): Some(bar)
```

How can I pass `foo=bar` as a System Property to the `console`?

Answer (score 9):

`run` forks but `console` doesn't, so simply `sbt -Dfoo=bar console`

If need be you can set it:

- in the sbt `shell` with `eval sys.props("foo") = "bar"`
- in the REPL (`console`) with `sys.props("foo") = "bar"`
- in `build.sbt` with `val setFoo = sys.props("foo") = "bar"`

Answer (score 1):

I can get system properties using the console with the following:

```
sbt console -Dturkey=fried

scala> sys.props.get("turkey")
res1: Option[String] = Some(fried)
```