# Default arguments for run task

Tags: sbt

My project needs several arguments to start. Something like this

```
sbt run -DONE_ARG.0=some_big_string -DANOTHER_ARG=another_big_string -DONE_MORE_ARG=with_big_value
```

In most cases, these args have typical values. Can I define default values for these arguments in build.sbt if they are not set in command line?

Comment: it really depends on how and where you read these values.

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc they are read by library code, I can't control it.

Comment: is this answering what you need [setting-system-properties-with-sbt-run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155870/setting-system-properties-with-sbt-run)

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc I need the ability to override the default values if the arguments are given on the command line. I do not see this possibility in the answers on the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are setting system properties, you can also check those properties inside the build and configure them if they are not there yet.

You need to set the `javaOptions` if `fork` is `true`. Otherwise you can simply change the system properties of the currently running JVM.

```scala
val defaultOptions = Map(
  "ONE_ARG.0" -> "some_big_string",
  "ANOTHER_ARG" -> "another_big_string",
  "ONE_MORE_ARG" -> "with_big_value"
)

// use default options, if not overriden
val options = (defaultOptions ++ sys.props.filterKeys(defaultOptions.keySet)).toMap

Compile / run := {
  val willFork = fork.value

  if (!willFork) {
    options.foreach { case (k, v) => sys.props(k) = v }
  }
  (Compile / run).inputTaskValue
}

javaOptions ++= {
  val willFork = fork.value

  if (willFork) {
    options
      .map { case (k, v) => s"-D$k=$v" }
      .toSeq
  } else {
    Seq.empty[String]
  }
}
```

Comment: When I redefine `run` it stops working :( I execute it and nothing happens, except that the properties are set.

Comment: And it stops accepting arguments. For example `run -Dlog.level=DEBUG` results in `Expected whitespace character `.

Answer (score 2):

I don't yet know how correct this is, but I did this and it works as expected:

```
lazy val defaultProperties = settingKey[Map[String, String]]("Default JVM properties")
lazy val setDefaultProps = taskKey[Unit]("Sets the default properties")

defaultProperties := Map(
  "ONE_ARG.0" -> "some_big_string",
  "ANOTHER_ARG" -> "another_big_string",
  "ONE_MORE_ARG" -> "with_big_value"
)

setDefaultProps := {
  val willFork = fork.value
  val defaults = defaultProperties.value
  val options = defaults ++ sys.props.filterKeys(defaults.keySet)

  if (!willFork) {
    options.foreach { case (k, v) => sys.props(k) = v }
  } else {
    javaOptions ++= options.map { case (k, v) => s"-D$k=$v" }.toSeq
  }
}

Compile / run := (Compile / run).dependsOn(setDefaultProps).evaluated
```

Thanks a lot to @cbley for the tip.